# Как упростить данный код js?

Tags: javascript

````
 const colors = document.getElementById("colors");
        const shoes = document.getElementById("shoes-img");
        const colors1 = document.getElementById("colors1");
        const shoes1 = document.getElementById("shoes-img1");  

        
        colors.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const currTab = e.target.dataset.span;
            changeClass(e.target);
            for(let i = 0; i < shoes.children.length; i++) {
                shoes.children[i].classList.remove('active');
                if(shoes.children[i].dataset.color == currTab) {
                    shoes.children[i].classList.add('active');
                }
            }
        });

        const changeClass = el => {
            for(let i = 0; i < colors.children.length; i++) {
                colors.children[i].classList.remove('active');
            }
            el.classList.add('active');
        }

        colors1.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const currTab1 = e.target.dataset.span;
            changeClass1(e.target);
            for(let i = 0; i < shoes1.children.length; i++) {
                shoes1.children[i].classList.remove('active');
                if(shoes1.children[i].dataset.color == currTab1) {
                    shoes1.children[i].classList.add('active');
                }
            }
        });

        const changeClass1 = el => {
            for(let i = 0; i < colors1.children.length; i++) {
                colors1.children[i].classList.remove('active');
            }
            el.classList.add('active');
        }```
````

Comment: налицо дублирование кода, все общее нужно вынести в отдельные функции и просто передавать параметрами данные, которые меняются

Comment: Вы забыли указать что делает этот ваш код. У вас нарушение Don’t repeat yourself